# Реализация map через unfold Scala

Tags: map, scala

Необходимо написать реализацию map через термины функции unfold на языке Scala.
Выглядеть это в итоге должно так:

`def map[B](a :List[A])(f: A => B): Stream[B] = unfold()()`

Соответственно в функцию unfold необходимо передать правильные аргументы.

Вот сама реализация функции unfold:

`def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A] = f(z) match {
    case Some((a, s)) => Stream.cons(a, unfold(s)(f))
    case None => Stream.empty
  }`

Очень прошу о помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def unfold[A, S](z: S)(f: S => Option[(A, S)]): Stream[A] = f(z) match {
  case Some((a, s)) => Stream.cons(a, unfold(s)(f))
  case None => Stream.empty
}

trait F[C] {

  def map[A](a: List[C])(f: C => A): Stream[A] = {

    def foo(li: List[C]): Option[(A, List[C])] = li match {
      case head :: body => Some(f(head) -> body)
      case Nil => None
    }

    unfold(a)(foo)
  }

}

// Проверка
val stream = new F[Int]{}.map(List(1, 2, 3))(_ * 2)
stream.mkString(",")
//res0: String = 2,4,6
```